# Android: Hyperlink in ListFragment ListView row

Tags: android, listview, hyperlink

Im trying to display hyperlinks (formated as hyperlink) in a listview row but not having any luck.  First I inflate the news_row view to a class variable in onCreateView for later

```
news_row = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_row,null);
```

I call setNews in onActivityCreate and look for the textview with hyperlinks and then popular the rows:

```
public void setNews(){           

        TextView textcontent = (TextView) news_row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        textcontent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        String[] matrix = {"_id", "title", "content", "date"};
        String[] columns = {"title", "content", "date"};
        int[] layouts = {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2, R.id.text3};

        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(matrix);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < straNewsTitle.length; i++) {
            cursor.addRow(new Object[] {i, straNewsTitle[i], Html.fromHtml(straNewsContent[i]), straNewsDate[i] });
        } 
        SimpleCursorAdapter a = new SimpleCursorAdapter(fa, R.layout.news_row, cursor, columns, layouts);           
        setListAdapter(a);
}
```

straNewsContent holds body text for a news item which may contain html hyperlink tags.  My news_row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffefe5" android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="15px" android:paddingRight="15px" android:paddingBottom="5px" android:paddingTop="5px">
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#666666" 
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:background="#ffefe5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text2"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
    android:textColor="#666666" 
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:background="#ffefe5"
    android:autoLink="web|email" 
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
    android:textColor="#666666" 
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:background="#ffefe5" 
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

android:autoLink="web|email" works great for strings that are formatted urls but html tags aren't being rendered.  Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I had to implement my own BaseAdapter and make the change in getView().

Answer (score 0):

Try [Html.fromHtml(String source)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29), which will take an HTML snippet as input and output a string formatted for putting in your TextView.

For instance, here's a snippet from the ApiDemos app:

```
  TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
  t3.setText(
  Html.fromHtml(
        "<b>text3:</b>  Text with a " +
        "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> " +
        "created in the Java source code using HTML."));
  t3.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```